# Quarentine modification to the SIR-model intepretation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to model the corona virus using the SIR model. I added in a new parameter to the model, that would simulate quarantine. My goal is to see what the effect of quarantine of the infectious would be, and thus not accounting for social distancing.

The equations using the new c parameter become:

$$S'(t)=-a \times S(t) \times I(t) $$

$$I'(t)=a \times S(t) \times I(t)-b \times I(t)-c \times a \times S(t) \times I(t) $$

$$R'(t)=b \times I(t)+c \times a \times S(t) \times I(t) $$

If t is measured in weeks, is it then true that this would put c percent of the newly infectious into R each week?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I sugest that you type `\times` to get $\times$ instead of $*$.

Comment: Or use `\cdot` for a more modest dot. Note that there is no reliable time series of infected persons as the tests are not suitable to prove the presence of a virus or indicate any specific infectious disease, any statistic of positive cases is influenced by the whims of the bureaucracy counting them (first by deciding on whom to test, then also how to evaluate the in general ambiguous results). There is no universal distinction of illness or death with positive marker test or due to positive marker test, which would for instance reduce the cases in Italy by a factor of $>10$.

Answer (score 2):

Your model modification implies a direct transfer from susceptible to recovered (implying directly immune or dead instead of a transmission event).

Social distancing and lock-down however works more to reduce the encounter rate of susceptible and infected, suggesting a piecewise constant or linear function for $a$. Let's try this out. During the lock-down, reduce the transmission rate by a factor of 3. To be more realistic, introduce a category for the severely ill that require bed-rest. Assume that those are under an effective quarantine and thus do not contribute to transmission. Also, add on a twice as long recovery period, so that on average if an infected person stays that way for 7 days, with 80% probability that person is then recovered with no or mild symptoms, and with 20% probability gets more severe symptoms requiring on average 14 days bed rest until resolution one way or the other. Note that the "active cases" are mostly from the "bedrest" category, with a small percentage, 10%-20%, of the "infected" added.

Extending code from https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925986/3088138 I get the following image for some semi-realistic guesses (this breaks down rapidly if you look too closely for similarities)

[image]

If you want to play around with this and have a python installation, the code for this "applet" is

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, TextBox

p = 1                                                       #population
i = 1e-4*p                                                  #infected
s = p-i                                                     #susceptible
l = 0                                                       #(severely) ill
r = 0                                                       #recovered/removed

recov_rate = 0.1                                            #recovery parameter
trans_rate = 3.5 * recov_rate                               #transmission parameter

lockStart = 30                                              #lockdown start
lockStop = 75                                               #lockdown stop

initialTime = 0
deltaTime = 0.001                                           #smaller the delta, better the approximation to a real derivative
maxTime = 200                                             #more number of points, better is the curve generated

#differential equations being expressed as functions to
#calculate rate of change between time intervals of the
#different quantities i.e susceptible, infected and recovered/removed

def SIR_prime(t,SIR): # solver expects t argument, even if not used
    S,I,L,R = SIR
    trans, recov = trans_rate, recov_rate
    if lockStart<t<lockStop: trans /= 3;
    dS = (-trans*I/p) * S 
    dI = (trans*S/p-recov) * I
    dL = recov*(0.2*I-0.5*L) 
    dR = recov*(0.8*I+0.5*L)
    return [dS, dI, dL, dR]

def genData():
    SIR = solve_ivp(SIR_prime, [0,maxTime], [s,i,l,r], method="Radau", dense_output=True)
    time = np.linspace(0,SIR.t[-1],1001)
    sVals, iVals, lVals, rVals = SIR.sol(time)
    return (time, sVals, iVals, lVals, rVals)


#=========== Construct GUI layout ==========================
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4, top=0.94)

plt.title('SIR epidemiology curves for a disease')

plt.xlim(0, maxTime+1)
plt.ylim(0, p*1.4)
plt.grid();
plt.xlabel('Time (t)')
plt.ylabel('Population (p)')


susceptible, = ax.plot([0],[0], label='Susceptible', color='b')
infected, = ax.plot([0],[0], label='Infected', color='y')
ill_bedrest, = ax.plot([0],[0], label='Ill (bedrest+)', color='r')
recovered, = ax.plot([0],[0], label='Recovered/Removed', color='g')

plt.legend()

transmissionAxes = plt.axes([0.15, 0.26, 0.775, 0.03], facecolor='white')
recoveryAxes = plt.axes([0.15, 0.22, 0.775, 0.03], facecolor='white')
lockStartAxes = plt.axes([0.15, 0.18, 0.775, 0.03], facecolor='white')
lockStopAxes = plt.axes([0.15, 0.14, 0.775, 0.03], facecolor='white')
timeAxes = plt.axes([0.15, 0.10, 0.775, 0.03], facecolor='white')

transmissionSlider = Slider(transmissionAxes, 'Transmission', 0, 0.5, valinit=trans_rate, valstep=0.002, valfmt="%.3f")
recoverySlider = Slider(recoveryAxes, 'Recovery', 0, 0.3, valinit=recov_rate, valstep=0.002, valfmt="%.3f")
lockStartSlider = Slider(lockStartAxes, 'Lockdown start', 0, 100, valinit=lockStart, valstep=1, valfmt="%i")
lockStopSlider = Slider(lockStopAxes, 'Lockdown stop', 0, 100, valinit=lockStop, valstep=1, valfmt="%i")
timeSlider = Slider(timeAxes, 'Max time', 0, 400, valinit=maxTime, valstep=1, valfmt="%i")

#================ GUI control =============

def updateTransmission(newVal):
    global trans_rate
    trans_rate = newVal
    updatePlot()

def updateRecovery(newVal):
    global recov_rate
    recov_rate = newVal
    updatePlot()

def updateMaxTime(newVal):
    global maxTime
    maxTime = newVal
    updatePlot()

def updateLockStart(newVal):
    global lockStart
    lockStart = newVal
    updatePlot()

def updateLockStop(newVal):
    global lockStop
    lockStop = newVal
    updatePlot()


def updatePlot():
    newData = genData()

    susceptible.set_data(newData[0],newData[1])
    infected.set_data(newData[0],newData[2])
    ill_bedrest.set_data(newData[0],newData[3])
    recovered.set_data(newData[0],newData[4])

    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale()

    r_o.label.set_text(r'$R_O={:.2f}$'.format(trans_rate/recov_rate))

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()



transmissionSlider.on_changed(updateTransmission)
recoverySlider.on_changed(updateRecovery)
timeSlider.on_changed(updateMaxTime)
lockStartSlider.on_changed(updateLockStart)
lockStopSlider.on_changed(updateLockStop)

resetAxes = plt.axes([0.8, 0.02, 0.1, 0.05])
resetButton = Button(resetAxes, 'Reset', color='white')

r0Axes = plt.axes([0.5, 0.02, 0.1, 0.05], frame_on=False)
r_o = Button(r0Axes, r'$R_O={:.2f}$'.format(trans_rate/recov_rate), color='white')

def reset(event):
    transmissionSlider.reset()
    recoverySlider.reset()
    lockStartSlider.reset()
    lockStopSlider.reset()
    timeSlider.reset()

resetButton.on_clicked(reset)

updatePlot()
plt.show()
```